# Trying to the webhook with django. But it doesn't work

Tags: django, webhooks

I'm Trying to the webhook with django. But it doesn't work. Is something wrong?

recieved side of the page which is expecetd reload or updated by recieving POST request doesn't work at part the code below.

**return HttpResponse("RecievedData=" + s)**

I just want to imform the data and update the recieved side page.

[project.url]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from webhook.views import webhook

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include('app.urls')),
    
    path('webhook/', webhook),
]
```

[app-urls.py] ...... sender side

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name= "app"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    path('pos/', views.pos, name="pos")
    
]
```

[app-views.py] ... sender side

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic

import requests

class IndexView(generic.View):
    template_name= "app/index.html"
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

def pos(request):
    url= 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/webhook/'

    dt= {"foo": "bar"}

    r1= requests.post(url,dt)

    print("pos", r1)

    return redirect('app:index')
```

[webhook-views.py] ... reciever side

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    
    @csrf_exempt
    def webhook(request):
        s=""
        if request.method == 'POST':
            s= request.POST.get("foo") # <---- OK.
        
        return HttpResponse("RecievedData=" + s) # <---- Doesn't work Here.
```

[app-index.html] ... sender side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="{% url 'app:pos' %}">Post Data</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your error, what doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for reply. there is no error, and the recieved side recieve the POST data. But, dosen't work HttpResponse() .

Comment: What doesn't work?  Can you post to the `webhook` endpoint independently and and get the expected result?

Comment: the recieved page doesn't Update by [ return HttpResponse("RecievedData=" + s) ].

Comment: first independently confirm that your `webhook` view properly handles  your POST, then work from there.

Comment: maybe, I misunderstand mechanism of webhook reciever in Django...